# Customização do player de audio html5

Tags: javascript, html, css

Venho com está dúvidas a algum tempo, existe alguma possibilidade de customização do player de `audio` do html5. Até o momento sei que existe possibilidade utilizando plugins desenvolvidos em javascript, mais deste modo ainda não há encontrei à respeito.

Comment: Não entendi, você quer um modo que **não** utilize JavaScript? Tipo um que use somente CSS? Ou entendi errado?

Comment: O modo seria apenas utilizar o CSS para a customização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizar o player é impossível.

Contudo, você pode fazer diferente: deixe ele invisível, e crie seus próprios controles customizados, enviando os comandos diretamente para o player, via JavaScript.

Por exemplo:

```
<audio id="demo" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Reproduzir o áudio</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pausar o áudio</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Aumentar o volume</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Diminuir o volume</button>
</div>
```

*Esse exemplo foi retirado do site do MDN, onde você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre o assunto: [Utilizando áudio e vídeo com HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).